# How to align a TouchableOpacity with an icon to the right?

Tags: react-native, layout

I am trying to put my icon on the right side of the header. How do I do it? I am pretty new to react-native layout

I have tried alignSelf: 'flex-end' and right: 0, none of them will work.

```
                    <View style={Style.addModalContainer}>

                        <View style={Style.addModalHeader}>

                            <TouchableOpacity style={Style.addModalBackButton} hitSlop={{top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10}} onPress={() => this.openAddAvailabilityModal(false)}>

                                <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={24} />

                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </View>

                    </View>
```

```
    addModalContainer: {
        height: '90%',
        width: '95%',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    addModalHeader: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderBottomColor: '#DDDDDD',
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    },
    addModalBackButton: {
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        right: 0,
    },
```

I want the icon to be aligned on the right

Answer (score 2):

instead of using:

```
addModalBackButton: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    right: 0,
},
```

Change flexDirection of 'addModalHeader' to 'row-reverse'

```
addModalHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked the question long ago, but maybe there are those who have similar problems :) You thought well and bottom properties must work. But I made a small change.

`alignSelf: 'flex-end',
right: 0,`

you will set this properties inside **addModalContainer**.

```
addModalContainer: {
    height: '90%',
    width: '95%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end', 
    right: 0,
},
```